# will concurrency cause Socket.io + Nodejs fail

Tags: node.js, sockets, concurrency

Okay Im developing a game which will require real-communication so I am using socket.io in this so I am currently trying to handle disconnect of the game my concern that another event might emit concurrently while I handle the disconnect making the game freeze. I know that nodejs is single threaded but what if I am running a multiple container for my server I know that I should use a load balance so that requests of a certain socket go to the same instance but this might make concurrent event be emiited while disconnection of a user? SO how could this be handled or did I miss something when scaling socket.io in my backend?

A solution I thought of is that I could balance requests by gameId so the users who are in the same game would endUp join the same instance of my server but I have no idea if something like this is applicable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, yes node is 'single threaded' from an eventloop perspective so all your request will be queued up as they come in.

What that means if you are using socket.io for your 'game' then each emit to the server would be executed synchronously one after the other. Now with that said, Node is very efficient here but under a heavy load or long / blocking scripts can bring the server down to a crawl.

Fortunately you can cluster node quite easily with tool like PM2, this will let you use each 'core' on the VM and load balance between all of them.

BUT.. this leaves us in a bit of a bind if we need to maintain state, because PM2 actually spawns a new version of your app on each 'core' it cant talk between each instance meaning sessions are not shared between the running instances nor are files stored on each VM accessible between etc..

This means, to scale node / socket.io at scale you will need to break out a few parts of your application, this will require a few additional services so your stack may look like

1. Node servers ( this can be multiple VMs with a LB infront or a container )
2. Redis server ( This is where you will store sessions information AND socket.io data )

Now, there are many ways to architect this but as an example, one way may be
(Assuming you would be using pm2 for clustering you would have)

1. Game node app - 2 VM's @ 2 vcpu running PM2 ( would be 4 running instances of the game)
2. Socket.io server - 2 VM's @ 2 vcpu running PM2 ( would be 4 running instances of the socket.io server)
3. Redis server ( depending on load, you may wish to have 2 separate instances, one for sessions and game items and another to manage socket.io )
4. Object store (S3 or other object store) to store images
5. Optional CDN

With Socket.io you will for sure want to use the redis.socket.io NPM. This will allow you to scale socket.io to multiple noted, the redis package for socket.io manages the connected clients, so even if a user connected on another socket server they will still be able to emit and receive messages

Not sure where you are hosting right now but there are many services available and depending on how much you want to manage you may want to look at services like 'apps' from digital ocean. It's basically a 'CAAS' service, where you can have you socket.io server in GIT and then deploy it out to a running container, DO will handle the balancing between each of your running 'APPs', so you can on-demand scale running instances up and down as needed. Its not the cheapest though and has some drawbacks from a bandwidth perspective etc but its nice if you have known spikes that allow you to scale up and down etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great explanation but if I may ask why isn't the node server and socket server the same. And does this architect will handle each event to the same room synchronously or each server instance might handle a different event for the same room(assuming user's of the room connected to different instances)?

Comment: There is no reason they cant be on the same server, its just when you are thinking in terms of scale it would be more performant to have them separated, assuming you have a 'node' webapp and a socket server. If there is just a node app then no need for another node app. For evens and rooms, this is where socket.io redis will come in to handle sending events to all users, regardless of of what server they connected to. So emit to room1 will tell all clustered socket servers to send to room1 on all instances

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it !!